# How to convert tiff to searchable pdf using alfresco and tesseact?

Tags: integration, ocr, alfresco, tesseract, alfresco-share

I want to convert *.PDF file to searchable *.PDF files using alfresco and tesseract OCR.

tesseract version 3.03 needs to be compiled and i need to generate setup of that using source code.Is there any other solution for the same.
Can anyone help for the same?

Comment: What did you try so far? How far did you get before hitting issues?

Comment: I have gone through this link.http://alfrescosolutionsv.blogspot.in/2014/07/alfresco-integration-with-tesseract.html.  But now I want to convert tiff to pdf but it's not working.

Comment: Would it be OK to transform the TIFF into a non-searchable PDF, then do a custom indexer which would still call out to Tesseract for those PDFs?

Comment: Could you please provide me more details or steps so I can follow it?

Comment: Please clarify your question. With "searchable PDF" usually a "Sandwich PDF" is meant. But your problem description sounds more like you want to make the contents of PDFs indexable by alfresco.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can use another tool which is directly performing pdf to searchable pdf conversion.This tool is using tesseract internally for this conversion.You can find more details on below link and configure same for alfresco.

http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1456756

command

**pdfocr -i input.pdf -o output.pdf**

Answer (score 4):

You'll need Tesseract 3.03 or later for searchable PDF output feature.

```
tesseract yourimage.tif out pdf
```

Comment: can you give me link for that?I am not able to find tesseract 3.03

Comment: It can be downloaded from the Repository: https://code.google.com/p/tesseract-ocr/source/checkout. You'll have to build it.

Comment: Is there any installer for tesseract version 3.03.Those things are only available for version 3.02.Do i need to compile and generate that?

Comment: Yes. There are VS2008/2010 solutions in the Repo. VS2013 solution is also [available](https://github.com/charlesw/tesseract-vs2012).